# need to store records in Xml Child with loop

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have requirement to add data from list<> to xml file. I am using XDocument and creating element to create and store data in xml. Now I have multiple  and I am trying to use foreach loop to store person data STAFFID but it is giving me error.

```
public void generateXMLFile(List<UWL> myList )
{          
        XDocument objXDoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("Institution",
         new XElement("RECID", myList[0].recid),
         new XElement("UKPRN", myList[0].UKPRN),
         new XElement("Person",

             foreach(var m in myList)
             {
                new XElement("STAFFID", m.STAFFID)
             } 
          )
         )
        );

        objXDoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "true");
        //
        objXDoc.Save(@"C:\Test\generated.xml");

        //Completed.......//
        MessageBox.Show("Process Completed......");
}
```

Comment: Let me guess which error you have..

Comment: it the foreach loop area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide content for `Person` element. Foreach loop does not return anything. So, valid code will be:

```
XDocument objXDoc = new XDocument(
  new XElement("Institution",
   new XElement("RECID", myList[0].recid),
   new XElement("UKPRN", myList[0].UKPRN),
   new XElement("Person",
       myList.Select(m => new XElement("STAFFID", m.STAFFID))
  )
 )
);
```

That creates collection of `STAFFID` elements and sets this collection as content of `Person` element.